# OpenAI Assistants API: How do I upload a file and use it as a knowledge base?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api, openai-assistants-api

My goal is to create a chatbot that I can provide a file to that holds a bunch of text, and then use the OpenAI Assistants API to actually use the file when querying my chatbot. I will use the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model to answer the questions.

The code I have is the following:

```
file_response = client.files.create(
   file=open("website_content.txt", "rb"),
   purpose="assistants"
)

query_response = client.assistants.query(
   assistant_id="my_assistant_id", 
   input="Tell me about xxx?",
   files=[file_response['id']] 
)
```

However, this is not working, for what I think could be a few things. For one, I don't fully understand the way it is supposed to work, so I was looking for some guidance. I have already created an assistant via the dashboard, but now I want to just upload a file and then query it. Do I have to use something else, like "threads" via the API, or no?

How do I do this?

Comment: I suggest you watch my [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZwYQnIX_0) on this matter.

Comment: @RokBenko hey this helped a lot, thanks for sharing! The only problem now is that i keep getting ```Assistant: I currently don't have access to the contents of the file you uploaded. Could you provide me with some details or specific questions from the 
document so I can assist you effectively?```, although I followed your script exactly from the repo. Any advice?

Comment: See my answer below, especially the note at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [customer support chatbot](https://github.com/rokbenko/ai-playground/tree/main/openai-tutorials/4-Build_customer_support_chatbot) and made a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/xbgX8fu78DI) about it.

The process is as follows:

**Step 1: Upload a File with an "assistants" purpose**

```
my_file = client.files.create(
  file=open("knowledge.txt", "rb"),
  purpose='assistants'
)
```

**Step 2: Create an Assistant**

```
my_assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
    instructions="You are a customer support chatbot. Use your knowledge base to best respond to customer queries.",
    name="Customer Support Chatbot",
    tools=[{"type": "retrieval"}]
)
```

**Step 3: Create a Thread**

```
my_thread = client.beta.threads.create()
```

**Step 4: Add a Message to a Thread**

```
my_thread_message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
  thread_id=my_thread.id,
  role="user",
  content="What can I buy in your online store?",
  file_ids=[my_file.id]
)
```

**Step 5: Run the Assistant**

```
my_run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
  thread_id=my_thread.id,
  assistant_id=my_assistant.id,
)
```

**Step 6: Periodically retrieve the Run to check on its status to see if it has moved to completed**

```
keep_retrieving_run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
    thread_id=my_thread.id,
    run_id=my_run.id
)
```

**Step 7: Retrieve the Messages added by the Assistant to the Thread once the run status is "completed"**

```
all_messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(
    thread_id=my_thread.id
)

print(f"User: {my_thread_message.content[0].text.value}")
print(f"Assistant: {all_messages.data[0].content[0].text.value}")
```

See the [full code](https://github.com/rokbenko/ai-playground/tree/main/openai-tutorials/4-Build_customer_support_chatbot).

### Important note

The assistant might sometimes behave strangely. The Assistants API is still in beta, and it seems that OpenAI has trouble keeping it realiable, as discussed on the official [OpenAI forum](https://community.openai.com/t/assistant-not-able-to-access-uploaded-file/524495/1).

The assistant might sometimes answer that it cannot access the files you uploaded. You might think you did something wrong, but if you run identical code later or the next day, the assistant will successfully access all files and give you an answer.

The weird responses I got were the following:

- *Assistant: I currently do not have access to the file you uploaded.
  Could you provide some details about what you're selling or any
  specific questions you have in mind?*
- *Assistant: I currently don't have the ability to directly access the
  contents of the file you uploaded. However, if you can provide some
  details or specific questions about the than happy to assist you in
  finding the information you need.*
- *Assistant: I currently don't have visibility into the specific
  contents of the file you've uploaded. Could you provide more details
  about the file or its contents so that I can assist you further?*
- *Assistant: I see you've uploaded a file. How can I assist you with
  it?*